# Using a variable instead of constants for properties in wxFormBuilder

Tags: wxpython, xrc, wxformbuilder

In widgets like the spinctrl or slider box, properties like the inital position, min and max values etc can be set to constants. Is there any way by which they can be specified as variables.

so the code

```
self.HDSpin = wx.SpinCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.SP_ARROW_KEYS, 0, 10, 0 )
```

becomes

```
self.HDSpin = wx.SpinCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.SP_ARROW_KEYS, params.minv, params.maxv, params.defaultv )
```

This will allow the parameters to be set at run time just before the dialog is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, in place of each variable enter a unique number: eg: 123401,123402,123403 etc. Once the "gui.py" autogenerated file is created, run a script with sed that replaces each number with the corresponding variable. I use the same to make the default strings runtime determined as opposed to hardcoded. With strvar01,strvar02 in the default string textboxes

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="gui.py"

sed -i 's/123401/HDMin/g' "$FILE"
sed -i 's/123402/HDDefault/g' "$FILE"
sed -i 's/123403/HDMax/g' "$FILE"
sed -i 's/u"strvar01"/DefaultStr1/g' "$FILE"
```

so the auto-generated code `self.Label1 = wx.StaticText(..., u"strvar01", ... )`

becomes: `self.Label1 = wx.StaticText(...,DefaultStr1, ... )`

where the value of `DefaultStr1` is set at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use variables like you would in a normal(non wxpython) python method.

Comment: wxformbuilder accepts only numers in the properties dialogs.. currently I give them constants some specific numbers for each variable.. eg `x` as `12301`. `y` as `12302` etc. Then I use a bash script with sed to add in the variables to the autogenerated file.

Comment: In that case it is a limitation of wxformbuilder, you will have to alter the code that it spits out or make a request to the developers that they add to its functionality.